# Query Store "Overall Resource Consumption" details

Tags: sql-server, query-store

I want to know how much total CPU a database has consumed for a given date span, for all queries.

I can see it in SSMS (under Query Store / Overall Resource Consumption), but how can I query for that programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Query Store GUI uses this T-SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'WITH DateGenerator AS
(
SELECT CAST(@interval_start_time AS DATETIME) DatePlaceHolder
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(d, 1, DatePlaceHolder)
FROM    DateGenerator
WHERE   DATEADD(d, 1, DatePlaceHolder) < @interval_end_time
), 
UnionAll AS
(
SELECT
    CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.count_executions)) as total_count_executions,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_duration*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) as total_duration,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_cpu_time*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) as total_cpu_time,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_logical_io_reads*rs.count_executions))*8,2) as total_logical_io_reads,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_logical_io_writes*rs.count_executions))*8,2) as total_logical_io_writes,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_physical_io_reads*rs.count_executions))*8,2) as total_physical_io_reads,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_clr_time*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) as total_clr_time,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_dop*rs.count_executions))*1,0) as total_dop,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_query_max_used_memory*rs.count_executions))*8,2) as total_query_max_used_memory,
    ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_rowcount*rs.count_executions))*1,0) as total_rowcount,
    DATEADD(d, ((DATEDIFF(d, 0, rs.last_execution_time))),0 ) as bucket_start,
    DATEADD(d, (1 + (DATEDIFF(d, 0, rs.last_execution_time))), 0) as bucket_end
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
WHERE NOT (rs.first_execution_time > @interval_end_time OR rs.last_execution_time < @interval_start_time)
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(d, 0, rs.last_execution_time)
)
SELECT 
    total_count_executions,
    total_duration,
    total_cpu_time,
    total_logical_io_reads,
    total_logical_io_writes,
    total_physical_io_reads,
    total_clr_time,
    total_dop,
    total_query_max_used_memory,
    total_rowcount,
    SWITCHOFFSET(bucket_start, DATEPART(tz, @interval_start_time)) , SWITCHOFFSET(bucket_end, DATEPART(tz, @interval_start_time))
FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bucket_start ORDER BY bucket_start, total_duration DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM UnionAll 
) as UnionAllResults
WHERE UnionAllResults.RowNumber = 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)',N'@interval_start_time datetimeoffset(7),@interval_end_time datetimeoffset(7)',@interval_start_time='2018-02-19 10:41:32.4646188 -06:00',@interval_end_time='2018-03-19 11:41:32.4646188 -05:00'
```

The results look like:

```
╔════════════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ total_count_executions ║ total_duration ║ total_cpu_time ║ total_logical_io_reads ║ total_logical_io_writes ║ total_physical_io_reads ║ total_clr_time ║ total_dop ║ total_query_max_used_memory ║ total_rowcount ║        (No column name)        ║        (No column name)        ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║                      2 ║           3.25 ║           3.25 ║                      0 ║                       0 ║                       0 ║              0 ║         2 ║                           0 ║              1 ║ 2018-03-18 18:00:00.000 -06:00 ║ 2018-03-19 18:00:00.000 -06:00 ║
╚════════════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

I saw that using a T-SQL statement trace against the server while simultaneous opening the GUI for "Overall Resource Consumption" on my local SQL Server 2016 instance.

I re-factored that above query down a bit, to:

```
DECLARE @interval_start_time datetimeoffset(7);
DECLARE @interval_end_time datetimeoffset(7);
SET @interval_start_time = '2018-02-19 10:41:32.4646188 -06:00';
SET @interval_end_time = '2018-03-19 11:41:32.4646188 -05:00';

SELECT
      total_count_executions = CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.count_executions))
    , total_duration = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_duration*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2)
    , total_cpu_time = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_cpu_time*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2)
    , total_logical_io_reads = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_logical_io_reads*rs.count_executions))*8,2)
    , total_logical_io_writes = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_logical_io_writes*rs.count_executions))*8,2)
    , total_physical_io_reads = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_physical_io_reads*rs.count_executions))*8,2)
    , total_clr_time = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_clr_time*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2)
    , total_dop = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_dop*rs.count_executions))*1,0)
    , total_query_max_used_memory = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_query_max_used_memory*rs.count_executions))*8,2)
    , total_rowcount = ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_rowcount*rs.count_executions))*1,0)
    , bucket_start = DATEADD(d, ((DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, rs.last_execution_time))),0 )
    , bucket_end = DATEADD(d, (1 + (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, rs.last_execution_time))), 0)
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
WHERE NOT (rs.first_execution_time > @interval_end_time OR rs.last_execution_time < @interval_start_time)
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, rs.last_execution_time)
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, rs.last_execution_time);
```

That returns a row for each day between the start end end dates provided.